# BLDC motor control method

Tags: c, embedded, motordriver

Recently I work with the BLDC motor control method, and I have confusion between the 180-degree commutation and the vector control method. Is it the same?

Comment: I think this question belongs to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I don't think the question is for StackOverflow.